# Best way to persist more than 100 values across postback in Asp.net 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql, ajax

I am working on an application with Asp.net 3.5. I need to take so many inputs from user including Personal info, Dependent info, plan info etc. having around more than 100 values.After taking input I need to send the user to review page to check for data entered.In case if he wish to change anything come back again on first page to correct the input and then go to review page.After correction he can proceed to save the data.So I would like to know what is the best way to persist this so much data across postback.

Comment: I would say some kind of client-side storage, for example LocalStorage (with fallback to other methods when it's not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of persisting the data you can put (make) the Review page html and hide the first portion of form when you show the review.

```
<div id="divForm" runat="server">
    form html
</div>
<div id="divReview" runat="server">
    Review html
</div>
```

In code bahind, when form is shown

```
divForm.Visible = true;
divReview.Visible = false;
```

In code bahind, when review is shown

```
divForm.Visible = false;
divReview.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Adam Heeg - Actually client is insisting to take all the inputs on the same page with different section using accordion.So I have a single page in all.                                               Adil - How to assign values for review in review DIV with out postback.

Comment: The suggested solution also require single page

Comment: Adil, my question is how to assign user's input values inside review div without postback.

Comment: You have to use client side script like javascript / jQuery

Comment: Thanks to all who share their expert and valuable comment

Answer (score 0):

With all the information the user is providing i hope you are making it a HTTPS page and that they are logged in.

Adil's answer is pretty good, but for security and time out issues I would add some complexity to help assure data is saved and doesn't have to be re-entered.

Just because they are not "saving" the information until after review does not mean you cannot save it do a database.  Since it is personal information you would be required to delete the entries on any error, timeout, or other event in which the user didn't explicitly choose to save it.

I suggest saving the data to a database, and since you have so many fields on a page I would make sure I have a save now button that has a disclosure on it so they know they can save their progress.  You could make a table of serialized data or just a regular table and put a timestamp on the data so at the end of a day or week you clear out all info that was not explicitly saved.

Remember, a database is for persisting data.  That includes saving user input at all points of your workflow.

Comment: I need to wrap this application in DNN.How can i achieve this, so as to take benefits of DNN as well.                                               Will below any module will work for this:                                           http://www.mandeeps.com/products/dotnetnuke-modules/live-wrapper.aspx?ref=dnns                                                      http://www.mandeeps.com/products/dotnetnuke-modules/live-content.aspx?ref=dnns                                                           http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/porto                               or other way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know DNN.